# Remove overlaping vertices in lines - QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology, overlapping-features, vertices

I am currently working with data that has a huge amount of topological errors. These are lines that are closed, in the place where the beginning of the line meets the end, someone added more than 2 vertexes. That causes all problems. There are too many features to correct them manually. 
I've tried clean, but it doesn't work as I expected. Is there any way to remove these overlaping vertices in lines and correct topology in QGIS or GRASS?

Comment: Simplifying with tolerance=0 is the common first aid.

Answer (score 4):

In the Processing Toolbox, search for "Remove duplicate vertices". There's an inbuilt tool which takes a tolerance and will strip out any duplicate vertices within that distance tolerance from other vertices.